# How to submit dynamically generated form with multiple levels of tabs and modules in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, forms

I have a registration form of residential complex with multiple levels, as you can see. I can edit and generate tabs by JS and jQuery, however I can't get the idea how to pass all that info to DB.

Screenshot: [image]

1. How can I submit all that information into my MySQL DB from this form which generates dynamically?
2. How to correctly generate tabs (when press + button)? I mean using arrays `$floor[0]` and etc.
3. Do I submit it by parts, or I can do by 1 submit button, as well as on the screenshot?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, I would strongly recommend you that you took a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get an' better idea of how SO works :) As your question is now it's very broad :)

Comment: Thanks. Kinda edited that stuff :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better solution is to use jquery wizard form.
[Click Here](http://codecanyon.net/item/ideabox-multipurpose-step-form/full_screen_preview/10818199?ref=jqueryrain) for demo. you can store your data in single table and get all the data at the end of form submition.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment...

You can store all information in one database table.

1. After clicking on submit button from tab 1 the action perform to redirect to tab 2 and get all the values of tab1 to tab2 but make them hidden. Note: you can store all previous values in session or any other ways.
2. As like for tab 3.
3. After clicking on tab 3 submit button your sql query runs which insert all the values in database table.

Hope this will help you.